# Upload images to the chat function as the message - socialkit script

Tags: javascript, php, html

Sorry questions I might be confusing but this should reveal that I can help from the teacher teacher here. This script is part of the social network socialkit script.

How to keep the chat function directly upload images could serve as the messaging menu.

```
<div class="chat-textarea">
<textarea class="auto-grow-input" onfocus="SK_focusChat();" onkeyup="SK_sendChatMessage(this.value,<?php echo $sk['chat']['recipient']['id']; ?>,event);"></textarea>


 <div class="advanced-options">

 <i class="icon-smile cursor-hand" onclick="javascript:$('.chat-emoticons-wrapper').toggle();"></i>
 <div class="chat-emoticons-wrapper">
<?php
 $emoticons = SK_getEmoticons();

if (is_array($emoticons)) {

foreach ($emoticons as $emo_code => $emo_icon) {
 echo '<img src="' . $emo_icon . '" width="16px" onclick="addEmoToChat(\'' . $emo_code . '\');">';
 }
 }
     ?>
 </div>
  </div>
 <input class="message-photo-input hidden" name="photos[]" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" onchange="SK_uploadMessageForm();">
 <div class="options-wrapper" style="float:left ; margin-top:5px">
 <i class="icon-camera progress-icon cursor-hand" title="<?php echo $lang['upload_photo']; ?>" valign="middle" onclick="$('.message-photo-input').click();"></i>
 </div>
 </div>
<?php
}
   ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript on the chat.

```
<script>
function SK_sendChatMessage(text,recipient_id,e) {
 document.title = document_title;
 textarea_wrapper = $('.chat-textarea');
 chat_messages_wrapper = $('.chat-messages');

 if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == 0) {
e.preventDefault();
textarea_wrapper.find('textarea').val(''); chat_messages_wrapper.append('<div class="chat-text align-right temp-text" align="right"><div class="text-wrapper float-right">' + text + '<div class="marker-out"><div class="marker-in"></div></div></div><div class="float-clear"></div></div>');

 $.post(SK_source() + '?t=chat&a=send_message', {text: text, recipient_id: recipient_id}, function (data) {
chat_messages_wrapper
.append(data.html)
.scrollTop(chat_messages_wrapper.prop('scrollHeight'))
.find('.temp-text')
 .remove();
 });
}
}

// upload photo chat
function SK_uploadMessageForm() {
document.title = document_title;
$('chat_messages_wrapper').submit();
SK_progressIconLoader($('.chat-textarea').find('.options-wrapper'));
}
</script>
```

**It javascript to be able to send picture messages**

```
function SK_sendMessageForm(e) {
    document.title = document_title;

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form.send-message-form').submit();
        SK_progressIconLoader($('.textarea-container').find('.options-wrapper'));
    }
}

function SK_uploadMessageForm() {
    document.title = document_title;
    $('form.send-message-form').submit();
    SK_progressIconLoader($('.textarea-container').find('.options-wrapper'));
}
```

**It send the form of a message**

```
        <div class="textarea-container" align="center">
            <form class="send-message-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <textarea class="message-textarea auto-grow-input" name="text" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['write_a_message_label']; ?>..." onkeyup="SK_sendMessageForm(event);" onfocus="SK_sendMessageForm(event);" data-height="22" disabled></textarea>
                <input class="message-photo-input hidden" name="photos[]" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" onchange="SK_uploadMessageForm();">
                <div class="options-wrapper">
                    <i class="icon-camera progress-icon cursor-hand" title="<?php echo $lang['upload_photo']; ?>" valign="middle" onclick="$('.message-photo-input').click();"></i>
                </div>
                <input name="timeline_id" value="<?php echo $sk['user']['id']; ?>" type="hidden">
                <input id="recipient-id" name="recipient_id" value="0" type="hidden">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My questions, this code upload image not work on chat.

```
<input class="message-photo-input hidden" name="photos[]" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" onchange="SK_uploadMessageForm();">
     <div class="options-wrapper" style="float:left ; margin-top:5px">
     <i class="icon-camera progress-icon cursor-hand" title="<?php echo $lang['upload_photo']; ?>" valign="middle" onclick="$('.message-photo-input').click();"></i>
     </div>
```

I look forward to help you all.

Comment: What is the question? :)

Comment: questions 

`<input class="message-photo-input hidden" name="photos[]" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" onchange="SK_uploadMessageForm();">
     <div class="options-wrapper" style="float:left ; margin-top:5px">
     <i class="icon-camera progress-icon cursor-hand" title="<?php echo $lang['upload_photo']; ?>" valign="middle" onclick="$('.message-photo-input').click();"></i>
     </div>`